# how to download a file from the server using php

Tags: php, sql

I have uploaded some files into the server,and i gave option to display them,so whenever some one clicks on that hyperlink,they will be able to see the contents of that file. But this is not happening with .msg files. So i want to download that file instead of opening the file from the browser.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 0):

It is so simple with html

```
<a href="url" download>Download file</a>
```

Comment: <a href="url" download>Download file</a>
you have wrote download after the url..what does that mean???

Comment: it will download the file without any script or code

Comment: It is only valid for HTML5 and only certain browsers support this attribute.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. Thank you for information.

Comment: yeah, i tried writing download in the <a> tag. It didnt download .msg file,instead it is opening it...can anyone suggest any alternative??